# View data in report in Address form

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I've started a directory project in C#.NET where I'm editing an xml file and using a dataset. There are 5 fields in the xml file to make up an Address. I want to display the address, like on an envelope, in a report and put 10 addresses on a page. I've been using Crystal Reports. If Crystal Reports is not the way to go with this, what reporting tool would be best to use.

Comment: Select mailling crystal report template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to create mailing address labels.

When I had to do the same thing, I ended up using the Mail Merge feature in MS-Word through automation using C#.  It's been working great for us and was pretty easy to set up.  Easier I suspect than Crystal Reports.

Google Mail Merge and C#.  You'll find a lot of resources.  Post any questions you have here.

I recall this one was useful:
[How to automate Microsoft Word to perform Mail Merge from Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301659)

Comment: Its taken me a while, but I wanted to try your idea and it is really neat. Thanks.